# How to Integrate DialogFlow CX with Whatsapp

Tags: twilio, dialogflow-es, chatbot, whatsapp, dialogflow-cx

I started Google DialogFlow CX. in integrations tab i dont see Twilio, as this was available in DialogFlow ES.

Is it posibble to integrate with Twilio?

Comment: CX may not support the Twilio integration ES has yet, it is very new and lacking in features at the moment (imo).  You don't NEED an official integration anyways, you can always build your own, but you'd have to do that with Whatsapp anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Jorge already said. You can create a api server that acts as a bridge between DialogFlow and twilio. I would recommend to:

1. Create a twilio studio. Add a custom HTTP request. Post to  the endpoint webhook and in the response, send it to twilio handler.
2. In the Server, create a dialogflow handler and one endpoint to recieve the incoming petitions from twilio studio

Answer (score 2):

There are many 3rd party tools that support the integration of Dialogflow CX with Whatsapp via Twilio.

Kommunicate is one such tool that provides Dialogflow CX & ES integrations along with WhatsApp integration.

It also provides a code-less integration where the setup can be done in a few minutes. It also comes with some cool features such as bot-to-human handoff and many customization features.

First, you need to integrate your Dialogflow CX agent in the Kommunicate account. Please refer to this [article](https://www.kommunicate.io/blog/integrate-dialogflow-cx-bot-website/) for the steps.

Once the Dialogflow CX is integrated. You need to add the Whatsapp setup from the dashboard. Refer to this [doc](https://docs.kommunicate.io/docs/whatsapp) for the setup steps.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need a middleware between CX & Twilio. This mw should interact with CX API and map the fields you want from CX responses on to the format that Twilio expects.

Create an endpoint that you can use as Webhook to configure Twilio and voilá, you got yourself an integration.